# Apollo Client 3: how to cache a mutation result into a nested collection? (collection within a collection)

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

In my Apollo Client 3 app, I am doing a mutation and want to cache the result into a collection which is nested within an item of a collection.

Specifically, I am creating a `comment` within a list of comments, each list within a post, each post within a list of posts. My app's data hierarchy looks like:

```
user 1
    profile 1
        post 1
            comment 1.1
            comment 1.2
        post 2
            comment 2.1
            comment 2.2
            < write mutation result here >
        post 3
            comment 3.1
            comment 3.2
            comment 3.3
        ...
```

In this situation, how would I best cache a created comment into its parent post's comment-collection? I am looking at the `useMutation` hook's `update` or `modify` config, but am not too sure.

For additional context, here is query that corresponds to the above data hierarchy:

```
query getUserPosts($userParams: GetUserParams!$postsPaginationParams: CursorPaginationParams!) {
  user(params: $userParams) {
    id
    profile {
      id
      # ...
      ownedPosts(pagination: $postsPaginationParams) {
        items {
          id
          # ...
          featuredComments {
            id
            primaryText
            creationTimestamp
            owner {
              id
              name
            }
          }
        }
        pagination {
          # ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my mutation:

```
input CreateCommentParams {
  ownerId: String!
  postId: String!
  primaryText: String!
}

mutation createComment($params: CreateCommentParams!) {
  createComment(params: $params) {
    id
    owner {
      id
      name
    }
    primaryText
    creationTimestamp
  }
}
```

And here is what the `useMutation` is so far:

```
useMutation(CREATE_COMMENT_MUTATION, {
  // ...
  update: (cache, { data }) => {
    if (data) {
      const cacheId = cache.identify(data.createComment);
      cache.modify({
        fields: {
          // ...how to update the comments array of the specific post? 
        }
      })
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the Post you are updating and update its featuredComments field like so:

```
useMutation(CREATE_COMMENT_MUTATION, {
  // ...
  update: (cache, { data }) => {
    cache.modify({
      id: cache.identify({
        __typename: 'Post', // Assuming your this is the _typename of your Post type in your schema
        id: postId,
      }),
      fields: {
        featuredComments: (previous, { toReference }) => [...previous, toReference(data.createComment)]
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my issue. Hours of struggling with the cache.. lol. You're the best.